# What is the right way to photograph in the gym?

Tags: lighting, light, sports

I need to photograph an instructor in the gym for a gallery of some lifting exercises (will be used in an application and on the web).

I want to look pretty dramatic and powerful, though instructive (that's their purpose).

The photography will be in an open gym (so the lighting is not powerful or any good) - What lighting should I use? How should I approach this?

I'm using Sony NEX-5N with 50mm lens.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to use a wider lens if you can to try and inject some drama, 50mm on APS-C will flatten the perspective quite a lot, and not put the viewer "in the scene".

An alternate way to make the images look more dramatic would be to use an off camera flash to light from the back or side. If you don't have the means to set up or trigger an off camera flash, a hotshoe flash with swivel action can be bounced off a nearby wall.

Comment: Thanks Matt. I can use 18mm. I though about using a projector from behind and a reflector from the side. Would that be a good idea?

Comment: @roman I've used a projector before, a flash is better but you've got to use what you've got. At least a continuous lightsource will let you see the effect you're getting. I would just use the projector directly, side on. By the time you've tried bouncing it off a reflector you might not have enough light to overpower the house lights.